# Installing Fedora 33 in VirtualBox on Windows host: nothing happens

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, installation, fedora, livecd

I'm trying to install Fedora 33 in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.

So I created a VDI file `Fedora.vdi` and inserted the iso file `Fedora-MATE_Compiz-Live-x8-_64-33-1.2.iso` .

[image: the settings]

Then I start the virtual machine and I get the menu and choose `Fedora-MATE_Compiz-Live 33`
[image: Menu]

And then, nothing happens. I get this black screen with a cursor blinking forever.
[image: black screen with cursor blinking forever]

The cdrom and hard disk symbols [image: cdrom symbol] [image: hard disk symbol] are supposed to have a green dot blinking, showing that there is some activity, but here nothing.

I then installed Fedora on another pc (and got no problem at all) and copied the VBOX and VDI files on the new laptop. And after starting the VM, it still does nothing. I get this black screen with the blinking cursor.

The logs are [here](https://pastebin.com/uxcYa626).

Any idea was it wrong?

Comment: Have you closed the window when it wasn't responding? Please be patient, as it might take a while to initialize, I faced the same thing but after a about 1 minute, I don't know, it resumed working properly, though I don't know if the cause of your issue is the same as mine, though if your RAM and/or HDD/SSD don't have sufficient space, surely it will be slow.

Comment: I left it open for more than 1 hour with 250 GB of HDD and 10 GB of RAM!

Comment: Then that's really interesting...